# pass textbox value from aspx to ashx

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a table in database with name and image
i want to load the image on the basis of name given in text box

```
string strQuery = "select img from exp where name='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
```

this is fine in aspx but in image handler ashx file i want to pass the value of this textbox
so that the same sql query can be applied

till now my handler file is

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class ShowImage : IHttpHandler
{ 
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string imageid = context.Request.QueryString["img"];

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=experiment;trusted_connection=true;");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select img from exp where (here i stuck....)", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dr[0]);
        con.Close();
        context.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

i want this in c# asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Button on the same page as the Textbox: 
You can put the following code in the button click handler.

```
Response.Redirect( "ShowImage.ashx?ImageName=" & Server.UrlEncode(TextBox1.Text));
```

This would allow you to access the Image in your image handler like this

```
string imageName = context.Request.QueryString["ImageName"];
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select img from exp where name='" + imageName  + "'", con);
```

Of course you should use a parameterized Query to guard against SQL injection.